# Laravel Eloquent, Multidimensional Relation Accessing

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-8

I have a 4 model Totally,

Project,
Board,
Task,
SubTask

Project -> hasMany -> Board
Project -> hasManyThrough -> Task
Board -> hasMany -> Task
Board -> hasManyThrough -> SubTask
Task -> hasMany -> SubTask

This is my Project Model,

```
namespace App\Models;
    
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Project extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    public function priority()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Priority::class);
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

    public function boards()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Board::class);
    }

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Task::class, Board::class);
    }

    public function subTasks()
    {

    }
}
```

Board Model,

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Board extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }

    public function subTasks()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(SubTask::class, Task::class);
    }
}
```

Task Model,

```
namespace App\Models;
    
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Task extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    public function subTasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SubTask::class);
    }
}
```

How can i access Project Subtasks with eloquent relation?

Comment: It really depends. But assuming you don't want to filter anything you can try to do `$project->boards()->subTasks()->get()`

Comment: I was tried this method, but its give me this error,

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::subTasks()

Comment: try calling it like this  $project->load('board','board. subTask');

the result should be something like this

"project": {
   .....,
  board: [
     {
       ....
      subtask: {
        ....
      }
   }
 ]
}

Comment: $project->load('board','board. subTask');

It is working thanks but this method giving me project, boards and sub tasks together. I want to access only subtasks.